# ReactJS form performance issue update array of object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dynamic form generated from array, I use form hook and setState to control it. I've run into performance issue: the input is laggy. I expect it would be smooth at least for now the state is not large.

```
const guests = ["adult", "child"];
const dynamicInputsDefaultState = guests.map((v, i) => ({
  [`fname#${i}`]: {
    value: ""
  }
}));

const useFormHook = () => {
  const [dynamicInputs, setDynamicInputs] = useState(dynamicInputsDefaultState);
  const handleInputChange = (e, guestIndex) => {
    if (guestIndex !== undefined) {
      const nextDynamicInputs = dynamicInputs.map((v, i) =>
        i === guestIndex
          ? {
              ...v,
              [e.target.name]: {
                ...v[e.target.name],
                value: e.target.value
              }
            }
          : v
      );

      setDynamicInputs(nextDynamicInputs);
    }
  };

  return {
    dynamicInputs,
    handleInputChange
  };
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-ride-fmp2b?file=/src/App.js:539-556

I'm stuck finding the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, it's because you are using `Guest` as a component and every time the input changes it has to rerender because the input value `dynamicInputs` is passed as a prop.

If it must be used this way, it is better to not abstract it like that and just put the content of `Guest` inside your return within `App` **OR** deconstruct `formHook` from inside `Guest` and get rid of its props altogether.

Also note, `Guest` does not even need to be a component, it can simply be a used as a function which will alleviate the issue (see Option #3 below).

**Option #1. Merging `Guest` into `App`**

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>
      {guests.map((guest, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <input
              name={`fname#${i}`}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              value={dynamicInputs[i][`fname#${i}`].value}
              type="text"
              placeholder={`${i} fname`}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

**Option #2 Using `formHook` within `Guest`**

```
export default function App() {
  const guests = ["adult", "child"];
  const Guests = () => {
    const { dynamicInputs, handleInputChange } = formHook();
    return (
      <div>
      {guests.map((guest, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <input
              name={`fname#${i}`}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              value={dynamicInputs[i][`fname#${i}`].value}
              type="text"
              placeholder={`${i} fname`}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Guests />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Option #3 Using a plain function instead of a functional component**

```
export default function App() {
  const { dynamicInputs, handleInputChange } = formHook();
  const guests = ["adult", "child"];

  const guestFunction = () => {
    return (
      <div>
      {guests.map((guest, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <input
              name={`fname#${i}`}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              value={dynamicInputs[i][`fname#${i}`].value}
              type="text"
              placeholder={`${i} fname`}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {guestFunction()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it does, but why?

Comment: You're passing `dynamicInputs` as a prop for `Guests` and then changing it every time with the input which forces a re-render. Either get rid of the component abstraction OR call `formHook` from within `Guests`.

Comment: @AndreThonas I edited my answer for more clarity and to explore other options

Comment: should I avoid abstracting as component? when should I do it? from your example if there's anything function prop maybe I should abstract to use function than component.

Comment: In this case it is better to just use a function. In general, only use components for things a bit more complex that require any combination of needing and manipulating *its own state* or needing to perform/derive things throughout its lifecycle--of course, components can also do OTHER things but this should be the bare minimum.